# ¿Como habilitar boton de servidor asp.net con jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar tengo un botón de servidor asp.net y lo quiero habilitar con jquery pero todavía no lo consigo aquí dejo mi código.

Gracias.

```js
 $("[id*=btnGuardar]").removeAttr("disabled",true);
```

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnGuardar" runat="server" Text="Guardar" Enabled="false"  />
```

Comment: $('#btnGuardar').prop('disabled', false); //esto lo habilitara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo pruebas usando un boton de html el selector funciona

```js
$(function(){

    $("[id*='btnGuardar']").removeAttr("disabled");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btnGuardar" disabled="true">Guardar</button>
```

Pero valida que `jquery` este aplicando y que el codigo si aplica cuando carga la pagina este dentro del `ready` por eso uso `$(function(){`

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini exactamente con boton de htm si funciona pero tengo un boton de servidor el cual me devuelve datos y hasta ahora no he podido habilitar el boton con jquery. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: en un boton de servidor de asp.net tambien debe funcionar, pero valida que la ejecucion pasa por ese punto que remueve el atributo. Valida que no tengas un error de javascript en la consola del browser, y que el contexto donde pones ese codigo sino es un evento de otro control que este dentro del ready como mencione